# Getting <Owner Execute Access Denied!> while creating job in autosys

Tags: job-scheduling, autosys

I am very new to Autosys. I want to create a new application and then add some jobs for the application in autosys. I have taken the following steps till now:

1. installed agent on the machine
2. created jil for machine. autoping success.
3. Create three application groups application_read, application_write and application_execute
4. Created an as_owner,as_machine and as_job policy.

I am getting the following error:

```
 Owner Execute Access Denied!
No policies granting access to resource.
Class: as-owner Resource: produsr User: ellen Access: execute
```

What am I missing? Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this the first job you are creating? Do you have the rights to create jobs? Are you guys using native or EEM security? Most likely you are not setup properly. Please check with your admin to look at your privilages.

Comment: We were using EEM. The issue is resolved now, there was an issue with the admin user that we have and its permissions.